# how to write a query in sequelize to find all todos associated with user_id

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, sequelize.js

I am writing first todo list app using node express ejs and sequelize with sqlite

my sqlite.js file for database schemas is as follow

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: "sqlite",
  storage: "./src/backend/databases/database.sqlite",
});

const users = sequelize.define("user", {
   username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

const lists = sequelize.define("list", {
  item: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  edit: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
  },
  done: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  user_id: {
    type: Sequelize.NUMBER,
  },
});


sequelize
  .sync()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("tables have been successfully created");
    //  return sequelize.drop();
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));

module.exports = {
  users: users,
  lists: lists,
};
```

I want to access and display all the todos related to user_id. i have used sequelize findall method as following

```
const dbConn = require("../databases/sqlite.js");
const list = dbConn.list;

 list.findAll({ where: { user_id: user_id } }).then((todoList) => {
    res
      .render("profile", { todoList: todoList })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  });
```

but I am failed to display in the ejs file. it says todo list is undefined

ejs file

```
 <div class="addedTask">
            <h3>Added tasks</h3>
              <% for( let i = 0; i< todoList.length ; i++){ %>
                <% console.log(todoList[i])%>
              <% } %>
          </div>
```

error shown is -- 
[ todoList is not defined ]

how do I change my approach to show all the todos associated with single user_id

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
list.findAll({ where: { user_id: user_id } }).then((todoLists) => {
    res
      .render("profile", { todoLists });
  }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

can you please tell me where are you getting the `user_id` from ?

Comment: user_id is in lists schema. here user_id is associated with users table. so when user logs in he should see the todo made by user

Comment: iam talking about the user_id variable {user_id: **user_id** }